# Controlling a scroll area by a simple Scroll bar in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, scroll, scrollbar

My objective it to to scroll the scroll are up and down with respect to the scroll bar in Qt,

i have only 1 scroll areal in my form

I am using Qt Creator and i think that there must be a simple way to do it. by a simple signal slot mechanism

i will appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You want [QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qscrollarea.html). If you only want to scroll in one direction, [set the policy](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#horizontalScrollBarPolicy-prop).

Comment: can u be more specific plz , ur answer is a bit vague

Comment: If `w` is the widget you want to scroll, `(new QScrollArea(parent))->setWidget(w);` is sufficient. RTFM, Qt documentation is exemplary.

Comment: please am new to Qt , can u be more specifik , more details and more code plz

Comment: Seriously, [Qt explains itself better than I can](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/widgets-tutorial.html)

Comment: i would really appreciate it if u can send me example on: karim.eltel@hotmail.com , am just new to this and i cant learn only by example , please make sure to attach ur source code

Comment: I am not going to write your code for you. People will gladly help you **if you show evidence of your own effort first**.